# Expand previous path in SASS

Tags: css, sass

I have a little issue with paths/selectors in Sass right now.
I got something like this:

```
&.foo {
  some-stuff .class,
  some-stuff ul,
  other-stuff .all {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

Now I'd like to make the color blue when the first path is &.foo.bar for example:

```
&.foo {
  some-stuff .class,
  some-stuff ul,
  other-stuff .all {
    color: red;
    // This obviously doesn't work, it's just here to show
    // what I want to do easier
    &.bar {
      color: blue;
    }
  }
}

// Compile to

.foo some-stuff .class,
.foo some-stuff ul,
.foo other-stuff .all {
  color: red;
}

.foo.bar some-stuff .class,
.foo.bar some-stuff ul,
.foo.bar other-stuff .all {
  color: blue;
}
```

Is there any way to accomplish that?

I tried to use variables to store the current selector with the [selector-parse Function](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#selector_parse-instance_method) but it didn't work out like I wanted it. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried `&.bar some-stuff .class` as a nested selector inside the `&.foo`?

Comment: That would work out, but I'd have to re-type everything with all underlying selectors again. I'd like to do it as DRY as possible. Updated the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks allot!

Comment: I had accidentally deleted that gist I posted in comments. Since the code is anyway there in the answer, I've left it as-is and removed my comment. Please don't mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`selector-replace`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#selector_replace-instance_method) function instead of the [`selector-parse`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#selector_parse-instance_method) function to replace the `.foo` with `.foo.bar` in the full parent selector.

```css
div{
  &.foo {
    some-stuff .class,
    some-stuff ul,
    other-stuff .all {
      color: red;
      @at-root #{selector-replace(&, '.foo', '.foo.bar')} {
        color: blue;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When compiled, it would result in the following CSS:

```
div.foo some-stuff .class,
div.foo some-stuff ul,
div.foo other-stuff .all {
  color: red;
}
div.foo.bar some-stuff .class, 
div.foo.bar some-stuff ul, 
div.foo.bar other-stuff .all {
  color: blue;
}
```